# 2nd Twitter Feed to Facebook Page (already have Feed to Account)

Tags: facebook, twitter

Like many others, I have my personal Twitter feed linked to my Facebook account.

In addition, though, I would like to link a second Twitter feed to a Page.  But trying to connect the second Twitter Account fails because I already have a Twitter account connected to my Facebook account.

I'm sure I'm not the first person to want to do this, but all the guides seem to suggest one-or-the-other.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Any solution to this? I have got the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer I have found for this conundrum is, within Facebook, to create a separate, new, user who is then assigned as a Page Admin - this can then link to the Twitter account.

The downside is that I now have multiple Facebook accounts (which I don't really want) and have to deal with Friend Requests to the (dormant) page admin user!

I am sure there is a neater solution... just I haven't found it!